# Is this seasonality additive or multiplicative?

Tags: time-series, seasonality

[image]Data from the M3 Comp Package
Is this additive or multiplicative seasonality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in https://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2014/11/09/additive-and-multiplicative-seasonality/  your data looks like possessing Multiplicative seasonality because the amplitude of the seasonal component is dependent on the level of the Time series.

However, one good way of figuring it out is to try both additive and multiplicative models and choosing the one having least rmse. This process has the advantage that it can be automated and it gives an answer based on a metric.

Comment: Thanks so much.